# Puppeteer - Multiple page navigation

Tags: puppeteer

Most puppeteer examples are related with one page scraping.

How to navigate over multiple pages clicking on submit buttons on each page, simulating a user site navigation?

Comment: Async/await (which puppeteer supports) allows for "good old" procedural prgramming where you just write script adding stuff to do, one thing to do after another. Why not do that for a start?

Comment: This is what I expected and already made. The question is, is there any other "good new" way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate in detail what problems you're facing in trying to "navigate over multiple pages and clicking on submit buttons"?

Comment: By clicking on a submit button you want to navigate multiple page? Can you explain your problem in details?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#browserpages),

> browser.pages() returns: >> Promise which
>   resolves to an array of all open pages. Non visible pages, such as
>   "background_page", will not be listed here. You can find them using
>   target.page().

```
const activePages = await browser.pages();
```

For example if there are 3 opened pages, You can handle them easily and use Page object's methods:

```
// take screenshots
await activePages[0].screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png' });
await activePages[1].screenshot({path: 'screenshot1.png' });
await activePages[2].screenshot({path: 'screenshot2.png' });

// close first page
await activePages[0].close();
```